# Can't export HKLM registry key in C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I need to export a registry key from the HKLM hive to a file. This is a key which I've successfully created just a few lines back in the same program. I am using a Process object to have my C# program execute the shell command:

**cmd.exe /c regedit.exe /e C:\temp\CDPRegExport.txt HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NPTMigration**

If I execute my program, the file **C:\temp\CDPRegExport.txt** is not created. However, if I run the command above directly (in this same administrative console window) it works fine!

I tried adding an application manifest to ensure that my .NET program is running as an administrator.

I tried invoking reg.exe export instead of regedit.exe /e but the result is the same (I'm guessing the same DLL is ultimately being used by these 2 programs).

Here's the main Registry Export method:

```
static bool RegistryExport(string regKey, string destFile)
{
    Cmd cmd = new Cmd()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };
    cmd.Exec(@"regedit.exe", @"/e", destFile, regKey);
    Console.WriteLine("Standard Out:\r\n" + cmd.StandardOut);
    Console.WriteLine("Standard Error:\r\n" + cmd.StandardErr);

    if (!File.Exists(destFile))
    {
        AppContext.log.Critical(@"Registry export file ({0}) not found!", destFile);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
 }
```

...And here's Cmd.Exe():

```
public void Exec(string command, params string[] Parameters)
{

    string fullyQualifiedCommand = @"/c " + command + GetParameters(Parameters);
    Console.WriteLine(fullyQualifiedCommand);

    try
    {
        psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd", fullyQualifiedCommand)
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
        };
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = psi;
            process.Start();

            if (RedirectIOStreams)
            {
                StandardOut = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                StandardErr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            }
            process.WaitForExit();
         }

        NormalExit = true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        StandardOut = string.Empty;
        StandardErr = ex.ToString();
    }
}

private static string GetParameters(string[] Parameters)
{
    string expression = string.Empty;

    if (Parameters.Length == 0)
        return string.Empty;

    for (int index=0; index<Parameters.Length; index++)
    {
        if (Parameters[index].Contains(" "))
            expression += " \"" + Parameters[index] + "\"";
        else
            expression += " " + Parameters[index];
    }

    return expression;
}
```

When the program uses regedit.exe both standard out and standard error are simply blank.

When it uses **reg.exe** export however, standard error shows:
"ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value."

Again, this is odd because if I invoke the *exact same* reg.exe or regedit.exe syntax directly via the command window, it works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 32-bit process on 64-bit OS, you must disable the WOW64 file system redirection

This test works for me (Windows 10, VS 2015 ) =>

```
bool bWow64 = false;
IsWow64Process(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out bWow64);
if (bWow64)
{
    IntPtr OldValue = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool bRet = Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(out OldValue);
}
string sKey = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NPTMigration";
string sFile = @"C:\temp\CDPRegExport.txt";
using (Process process = new Process())
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    psi.FileName = "reg";
    psi.Arguments = "export " + "" + sKey + "" + " " + "" + sFile + "";
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo = psi;
    process.Start();
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        string sResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(sResult);
    }
}
```

with declarations :

```
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool IsWow64Process(IntPtr hProcess, out bool Wow64Process);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(out IntPtr OldValue);
```